# CurVe document class: reduce the extra horizontal space between the key and its content in a \entry* row

Tags: macros, spacing, horizontal-alignment, cv, curve-class

I am using **CurVe** document class to create my CV.

I want to know if there is anyway to reduce the extra horizontal space between the key and value in one entry (`\entry*[...]...`). As shown by **Figure 1**, the horizontal space I want to reduce is indicated by blue circles.

I am aware that the template probably uses the width of the widest key, but I want to reduce the extra horizontal space. Its presence is clear by seeing the first rubric (Education) where all keys are empty. Some horizontal space is occupied for nothing before the diamonds. Is there anyway to reduce or even remove it?

**Figure 1**:

[image]

A compilable code that reproduces the issue (MWE) can be found from this popular overleaf [repo](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-customised-curve-cv/mvmbhkwsnmwv).

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE! Please provide an MWE (I.e., a compilable code that reproduces the issue) of your question, so other users can use it as a starting point. More about MWEs: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that